# How can I ensure my service will get my Wearable Messages if possible?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am building an app that requires - assuming that the devices are able to communicate - to instantly send a message from Android Wear to execute a method on the device.

My way of doing this would be creating a service, that waits for the message. I have read using START_STICKY ensures the service always runs, and how to start it on startup.

Is this the way to go? Or should I rather use a Broadcast receiver? What is the recommended method?

Comment: Would users be opening your Android Wear app and hitting a button or would your Android Wear be sending its message while in the background?

Comment: @ianhanniballake they would need to open the app on wear and press a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Listen for Data Layer events documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html#Listen), the correct method for handling incoming messages while the app is not in the foreground is by implementing a [WearableListenerService](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/WearableListenerService.html) - it'll automatically be called when another device (such as your Wear device) sends a message.

Your `WearableListenerService` can then trigger any behavior it wants.